# Stick three containers and a problem with iPhone X

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to create three containers (UI Views) as in the following example:

[image]

As you can see, in my case the TopContainer (the orange one) and the BottomContainer (the red one) have different dimensions. Also, I have a MiddleContainer (the white one) which is **NOT** located in the middle of the screen or in the center. In fact, the BottomContainer is a bit larger than the TopContainer.

**Question: how can I keep them constrained no matter which phone my user has?**

I tried to constraint the three components to the margins and between each others but it's not enough because, in that case, XCode argues that for each component the height and the width are ambiguous. Therefore I tried to maintain also the Aspect Ratio for all the three components and it seems to work, but with iPhone X (like iPhone XS) I get a ugly bottom line, so the bottomContainer doesn't fill the whole screen.

I know that there should be a "Bottom Space to" to set up for my BottomContainer in order to solve this issue but apparently I have it not, as you can see on the right side of the following screenshot:

[image]

Do you have an idea of what I am doing wrong? Do you have an alternative way to proceed?

Comment: You could use a [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview) and set the constraints as [proportions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview/distribution) maybe?

Comment: What you want to achieve can you please be more clear? For example first and last container has specific height and middle one has changeable

Comment: I think OP wants the Middle white view as of fixed height, middle of screen and Top, Bottom view are of flexible height as per device. same as the iPhone Xs screen.

Comment: @EmreÖnder I would like to have the middleComponent to have a fixed height and the topComponent and bottomComponent to adapt to the device. I don't really need the aspect ratio to be maintained.

Comment: Adopt to the device but how? I mean for example white has 100pt and whole screen has 500pt. How should remaining 400pt (500 - 100) space aligned between top and bottom views?

Comment: You need to define where you need to place the middle view as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve it with a `UIStackView` with two `UIView` (orange and red). The `UIStackView` is set to distribute `Fill Proportionally`.

The orange view is the size of your orange view plus the size of the white view.

Then I'd add the white view as a child to the orange view and constrain it to the bottom of that view and with a fixed height.

To get rid of the bottom gap, set the bottom constraint to `Superview` instead of `Safe Area`.

See the screenshot for details:

[image: UIStackView + 2 UIViews with child view]

Comment: This was of great help. Many thanks, it works and it helped me to understand a bit more about how constraints work.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment, I think this is what you can do!

Align the "**middleComponent**" to the center vertically, to its superview.

Set the height to it, as you want to have a fixes height there.

Then pin the "**topComponent**"'s bottom to the top of "**middleComponent**".

Pin the top of your "**topComponent**" to the top of the superview.

Pin the top of your "**bottomComponent**" to the bottom of the "**middleComponent**"

Pin the bottom of your "**bottomComponent**" to the bottom of your superview.

All these views will have have their left and right pinned to the superview's left and right.

Hope this helps